# Excluded: Robots no index

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have configured web URL for crawling web content data. All the web data is crawling successfully in my GSA, but I am getting "**Excluded: Robots no index**" message in index diagnostic for one URL and document from that URL is not indexing in GSA.

document doesn't contains any [**META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"**] metatag.

have you observed such kind of behavior in GSA ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of the relevant robots.txt, there'll be a rule there if it's not in the actual page as metadata.

Comment: I have checked robot.txt file and not found any rule for disallow url pattern for this url....also their is no rule in page

Comment: Keep looking, you have a rule defined somewhere and the GSA is just honouring it.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Start and Block URLs>Do Not Follow Patterns in GSA configuration. It may have been excluded there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.  I first verified that my URL was not being excluded from indexing by using online robots.txt testers.  I then tested my link in "Start and Block URLs" on the GSA to make sure it didn't match any block filters.

Once those possibilities were eliminated, I went to Index -> Diagnostics -> Index Diagnostics, and selecting the applicable collection.  From there, once I drilled down to and clicked on the filename, there is a screen with a button to "Recrawl this URL."  Clicking this button resolved the issue for me.